# Asp.net mvc 2 Search form in Partial View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Hi could someone make a small example for me.

I wanna create a partial view with a textbox and a submit button. 
When the user hits the submit button, I want to redirect to the following url

/Search/SearchQuery/

UPDATE

//This is my searchBox.ascx

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", new { area = "eCommerce" }, FormMethod.Post, new { searchTerm = "searchTerm" })) %>
<% { %> 
<input name="searchTerm" type="search" results="5" placeholder="Product search" autofocus /> 
<input type="submit" value="Search"> 
<% } %>
```

And here is my SearchController

```
public string Index(string searchTerm)
    {
        return "your search term was "+ searchTerm;
    }
```

And finally my MapRoute

```
 context.MapRoute(
            "Search",                                          
            "Search/{searchTerm}/",                          
            new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", searchTerm = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
```

Now its possible to use /Search/searcTerm/ but when I use my searchBox it just redirects /Search but my SearchController returns `"your search term was test"`

Answer (score 2):

Look at

```
Html.BeginForm("SearchQuery", "Search")
{
}
```

Put your text field in between that statement.
Put a button in there as well.

That's it, basically, plenty of examples around...

Comment: Just to be clear the SearchQuery is the text the user enters.
And I already search the internet without any luck, but I just need a simple example.

Comment: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers.aspx
Scroll down untill you see "Listing 2". And go read a book on ASP.NET MVC now :)

Comment: Almost there
Added the following code

context.MapRoute(
                "Search",                                          
                "Search/{searchTerm}/",                          
                new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", searchTerm = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );

 public string Index(string searchTerm)
        {
            return "your search term was "+ searchTerm;
        }
This makes it possible for me to enter an url like /Search/Hello/ and get a searchterm = "Hello" which is great.

Comment: <% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", new { area = "eCommerce" }, FormMethod.Post, new { searchTerm = "searchTerm" })) %>
<% { %>
<input name="searchTerm" type="search" results="5" placeholder="Produkt søgning" autofocus />
<input type="submit" value="Søg">
<% } %>


My submit for, worket, but it don't use and url like /Search/Hello/ but my Index(string searchTerm) still get's the correct input, any idea of what im doing wrong?

Comment: please update your question, it's impossible to read code in a comment